# Black Scholes Differential Form

Tags: stochastic-calculus

My instructor has mostly self contained notes, where our textbook is mostly a reference. She has it written that 
$$
S_t = S_0e^{(\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2})t + \sigma W_t}
 \iff dS_t = S_t(\mu\, dt + \sigma\, dW_t). 
$$
I feel that basic differentiation of the exponential e implies that on the right hand side we should have $dS_t = S_t((\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2})\,dt + \sigma\, dW_t)$.

I'd appreciate understanding why the $\frac{\sigma^2}{2}$ disappears from the differentiation when this is a basic rule about differentiating the exponential $e$.

Comment: Does $dW_t$ follows normal distribution or lognormal?

Comment: Have you tried Itō-Doeblin?

Comment: $W_t$ follows the normal distribution with mean 0 and variance t.

Comment: @Clarinetist: We haven't gotten to Ito's Lemma yet.

Comment: You might find answers to this one helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894526/in-stochastic-calculus-why-do-we-have-dt2-0-and-other-results

Comment: @Misakov, you're actually correct. I can't believe I missed that. Thanks. If you put that link in a formal answer, I'll upvote you.

Comment: @Misakov, Sorry, I take it back. That doesn't help. Sorry.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. I don't even understand the whole BS-Formula haha. I assume you are taking some sort of actuarial exam?

Comment: I'm in a quant-finance program.

Comment: If you want to know why the $\frac{sigma^2}{2}$ disappear, one thing I can assure you is that you cannot use the usual way of taking differentials here. It has something to do with a branch callled stochastic calculus, and a lot of weird things could happen there. Still I think if you go ask your instructor, she should be able to offer some sort of "intuitive explanation" which, probably will not be that rigorous. Cheers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18208/discussion-between-misakov-and-user7348).

Comment: This is just a simple Ito Lemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer comes from Ito Lemma.

[image]

This differs from the regular calculus that there is an additional term on the right hand side. Stochastic calculus is different to regular calculus in that a Brownian Motion can't be differentiated with respect to t.

The additional term explains your observation.

Furthermore, this has nothing to do with Black-Scholes. Black-Scholes is a hedging strategy that replicates an option. Your formula is a GBM, and is lognormal distributed. It just happens that in the BS world, we assume the stock price exhibit log-normal returns.