# Confusion about $\ dW_t^2 $ and $\ dt^2$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, differential

I start learning stochastic calculus and always come across this 2 notations $\ dW_t^2 , dt^2 $

Does $\ dW_t^2$  mean $\ d(W_t)^2 $ or  $\  (dW_t)^2 $ ?

Similarly, does $\ dt^2$ means $\ d(t^2)$ or  $\ (dt)^2$?

Thanks.

Comment: check about quadratic variations, that shall help.

Comment: $dW_t^2 = (dW_t)^2$ and $dt^2 = (dt)^2$. See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1392586/36150), [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/894526/36150) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81865/36150)