# If we have a SDE $dX_t=b(X_t,t)dt+\sigma(X_t,t)dB_t$, why is $(dX_t)^2=\sigma^2(X_t)dt$?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $(X_t)$ be an Ito process with SDE 
$$dX_t=b(X_t,t)dt+\sigma(X_t,t)dB_t,$$
where $(B_t)$ is a Brownian Motion. Now Ito's formula says that
$$df(X_t)=f'(X_t)dX_t+\frac{1}{2} f'(X_t)(dX_t)^2$$
is an Ito process too. I always read in books and papers, that $(dX_t)^2=\sigma^2(X_t)dt$ but it is never stated why. Is there a short proof or a reference that I can read?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81865/36150) and the linked questions.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Wiener Process $dB^2=dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81865/wiener-process-db2-dt)

it's natural to **define**

$$\int_0^t g(B_s) \, dB_s^2 := \lim_{|\Pi| \to 0}\sum_{j=1}^n g(B_{t_{j-1}}) \cdot (B_{t_j}-B_{t_{j-1}})^2.$$

Consequently, using the result below we have

$$\int_0^t g(B_s) \, dB_s^2 = \int_0^t g(B_s) \, ds.$$

["Lecture 15. Quadratic variation of the Brownian motion paths](https://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2012/08/24/lecture-15-quadratic-variation-of-the-brownian-motion-paths/)

Let us denote

$$V_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( B_{t^n_k} -B_{t^n_{k-1}}\right)^2.  $$

Thanks to the stationarity and the independence of Brownian increments, we have:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \left( (V_n-t)^2\right)=\mathbb{E} \left(V_n^2\right)-2t\mathbb{E} \left( V_n\right)+t^2 \\
=\sum_{j,k=1}^n\mathbb{E} \left( \left( B_{t^n_j} -B_{t^n_{j-1}}\right)^2\left( B_{t^n_k}-B_{t^n_{k-1}}\right)^2\right)-t^2  
=\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbb{E} \left( \left( B_{t^n_j}-B_{t^n_{j-1}}\right)^4\right)+2\sum_{1\le j<k\le n}^n\mathbb{E} \left( \left( B_{t^n_j} -B_{t^n_{j-1}}\right)^2\left( B_{t^n_k}-B_{t^n_{k-1}}\right)^2\right)-t^2  
=\sum_{k=1}^n (t^n_k-t^n_{k-1})^2 \mathbb{E} \left( B_1^4\right)+2\sum_{1\le j<k\le n}^n (t^n_j-t^n_{j-1})(t^n_k-t^n_{k-1})-t^2  
=3\sum_{k=1}^n (t^n_j-t^n_{j-1})^2+2\sum_{1\le j<k\le n}^n (t^n_j-t^n_{j-1})(t^n_k-t^n_{k-1})-t^2  
=2\sum_{k=1}^n (t^n_k-t^n_{k-1})^2  
\le 2t\mid\Delta_n [0,t]\mid \rightarrow_{n \rightarrow +\infty} 0.
\end{align}